# "Everybody Loves a Lover" Isn't Z part of Everybody?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I have a short circuit when I try to think of this formula meaning "Everybody Loves a Lover":

$\forall x \forall y ~[ \exists z (L(x,z) \land L(z,x)) \Rightarrow L(y,x)]$

my problem is that if I divide the universe of all people in $X,Y,Z$. Then we say that for all $X$ and $Y$, $Y$ will love $X$ only if $X$ is lover with atleast one $Z$, this does not tell me that also all of the $Z$ will love every lover $X$.. so it is incomplete in defining "everybody loves a lover" because everybody is missing the $Z$ people. But if $Z$ is just a different name to define the all of the poeple and $Y$ is another way to define the all of the poeple then it is ok. So point is that $X,Y$,$Z$ are the same set right? but we use them separately so to define diverse role in between the different people at different "times"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are sets of people, but then also say things like '$Y$ will love $X$ if ...', because at that point you are treating $X$ and $Y$ as individual persons again, rather than as sets of people. Indeed, when you say '$Y$ will love $X$ if ...', then your $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are no different than variables $x$, $y$, and $z$.

What is going on, though, is that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all quantified, and when we use several quantifiers in a sentence, all quantifiers quantify over the exact same domain, which in this case is all people.

And so yes, what you say in the end is captures the right idea correct: since the $z$ comes from the exact same domain as the $y$, it will in the end be true that whatever you picked for $z$, which is some person, will at some point also be picked for $y$ (since $y$ is going to range over all persons), and hence also that $z$ will end up loving everybody, as desired, even though you do not explicitly state that about $z$ in the formula.

Comment: is it true to say that the predicate above also states that every lover loves himself? because at some point x = y?

Comment: @sylvester Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall x~\forall y~\Big(\exists z~\big(L(x,z)\wedge L(z,x)\big)\to L(y,x)\Big)$$

The formula says: "$\text{Any $x$ will$\underbrace{\text{ be loved by }}_{\text{may be unrequired}}$any $y$ if that $x$$\underbrace{\text{ loves and is loved by }}_{\text{mutual love}}$some $z$.}$"

Or compactly: "Anyone who is a lover, is loved by everyone."

It does *not* claim that every lover loves *everyone*.

---

However, the PreNex form *is* indeed:

$$\forall x~\forall y~\forall z~\Big(\big(L(x,z)\wedge L(z,x)\big)\to L(y,x)\Big)$$

"For any $x,y,z$, then $y$ will love $x$ *if* $x$ loves and is loved by $z$."

Comment: I suppose my mistake is to read x,y,z as distinct subsets of the set of all people when instead they may be calling the same person x,y or z at different times "along the definition"?

Comment: could you also tell me why you use the single arrow \to and not \Rightarrow to symbolise the implication? The course I am following ("Introduction to Mathematical Thinking") uses double arrows for implications. thanks

Comment: It is my preference to use the modern convention that $\to$ is the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (a logical connective) *within* a statement, and ${\implies}$ should reserved for logical consequence *between* statements.  But many authors still don't follow that, and some even persist in using the even older $\supset$.

Comment: great thanks, but do you think my previous comment is sensible? I think what my question was asking is:

Comment: if I divide the universe of all people in X,Y,Z. Then we say that for all X and Y, Y will love X only if X is lover with atleast one Z, this does not tell me that also all of the Z will love every lover X.. so it is incomplete in defining "everybody loves a lover" because everybody is missing the Z people. But if Z is just a different name to define the all of the poeple and Y is another way to define the all of the poeple then it is ok. So point is that X Y and Z are the same set right? but we use them separately so to define diverse role in between the different people at different "times"

Comment: ...if I am wrong my prolblem is that I am thinking too procedurally and not holystically

Comment: You don't *divide* the domain; $x, y, z$ are labels for entities in the same domain, and they *need* not be three distinct entities.